# there is much space between text and border

Tags: android, android-layout

how can i reduce the space between the border and the text.
the edittext like

```
    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:padding="0dp"
         android:layout_margin="0dp"
         android:hint="UCUS NO"
         android:textAlignment="center"
         android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
         android:visibility="gone"
         android:layout_weight="0.2"
         android:textSize="12sp">
     </EditText>
```

[image]
and there is much space beetwen the text and the borders

Comment: `android:visibility="gone"` you are referring to some other **EditText**

Comment: when button clicked it become visible

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by some reasons, the most probable is that EditText has a minHeight and minWidht* configured. Override it to remove the spaces.

*Remember that any touchable View should have at least 48dp to be user friendly.

Answer (score 0):

You should investigate `TextView` which is the parent of `EditText`. It contains a lot of methods for handling line spacing and font spacing.

What you probably have is a combination of those two settings creating what appears to be "extra space".

Which are these:

```
android:lineSpacingExtra
android:lineSpacingMultiplier
android:includeFontPadding
android:elegantTextHeight
```

Remember a couple things:

1. Even for all caps, you may have accent marks that extend above or below.
2. For lower case letters, you will have hanging character marks.
3. For text selection, you will need space for the highlight and selection markers.